# zsh: Abbreviation expansion, what does |& mean?

Tags: zsh

The [grml zsh configuration](http://grml.org/zsh/#grmlzshconfig) contains a zsh abbreviation for a command I have never seen before:

```
abk=(
#   key   # value                  (#d additional doc string)
#A# start
    # <snipped>
    'G'    '|& grep --color=auto '
```

I am wondering why the abbreviation `G` expands to `|&` and not `|`. So the question is:

**What is the difference between `|&` and `|`?**

Comment: It can be searched for in `man zshall` by entering `/\|&`. The pipe needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|&` is short form for `2>&1 |` – it redirects both stdout and stderr over the pipe.